# Move Files In Cocoa

Tags: macos, file, cocoa, nsfilemanager

I want to move a file from a folder to another folder

I used

```
[[NSFileManager defaultManager]moveItemAtPath:@"Folder/Filename.fileExtension" toPath:@"FolderToMoveTheFile" error:nil];
```

Is there something else to type in error: ?

Why it isn't move my file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would get the error by doing this:

```
NSError* error;
if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager]moveItemAtPath:@"Folder/Filename.fileExtension" toPath:@"FolderToMoveTheFile" error:&error])
{
    // handle error, typically using the NSError object pointed to by the error variable
    // In an app, you might want to pass it to a -presentError:... method of a convenient responder
    // This is good enough for debugging:
    NSLog(@"failed to move file: %@", error);
}
```

The second path that goes after `toPath:` must be the path *including the file name at the destination*. It is **not** correct to just specify the path to the directory into which you want to move the file.

Also, you should typically use absolute paths, not relative paths. You can use relative paths but that then depends on the current working directory for the process. That's arbitrary for apps launched from the Finder or Dock. It's really only meaningful for command-line tools launched from a shell (e.g. a Terminal window) where the user might be expected to `cd` to a directory and then provide relative paths as command-line arguments.

Comment: Really thanks. The problem was't the error but this  i doesn't included filename on destination path.